# Searching in Array of dictionary and displaying data in table view

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, dictionary

I have an array of dictionaries where I what to implement search functionality and display data on tableView cells.

Search works quite fine, I have tested it:

```
-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {

    NSString *dictionryKey = @"eViela";
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K CONTAINS [cd] %@", dictionryKey, searchText];
    NSArray *filteredArray = [self.allItems filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
    NSLog(@"%@", filteredArray);

    self.sortedText = filteredArray;

    [self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

Now I need tableView to fill data only for key "eViela" while user is typing info in search bar. As of now I can show only all items as per below code:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"SearchCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    EvielasLibrary *library = [[EvielasLibrary alloc] init];
    cell.textLabel.text = [[library.library objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] 
    return cell;
}
```

I know that it should be easy but I can't figure it out.

Thanks for help!

Comment: self.sortedText is your datasource array ?

Comment: No, it is MutableArray which I created to store values after sorting. allItems is my datasource array.

Comment: ok then when will you use self.sortedText array .

Comment: I need to use it instead of cell.textLabel.text = [[library.library objectAtIndex:indexPath.row], so it will be something like this: cell.textLabel.text = [self.sortedText objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; but the problem is that I am getting crash since objectAtIndex 0 is beyond bounds which is logical since I did not typed any text in search bar yet so array is empty. So how can I show by allItems array before text is typed in search bar and only after text is typed tableView will start filling cells with sorted values?

Comment: this crash occurred due to your are returned wrong count in numberofRowInIndexPath. if you your used self.sortedText  in cellforRowAtIndexpath . so you must need to retun that array in numberofRowInIndexPath.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get Model from array instead of create new one .

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"SearchCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    EvielasLibrary *library = [self.sortedText objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; // assume that  self.sortedText is your data source array of tableview
    cell.textLabel.text = @"" // populate your string here  
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableArray *arrayForTableView = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSString *dictionryKey = @"eViela";
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[c] %@",dictionryKey];
NSArray *filteredArray = [self.allItems filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
for (NSInteger i = 0; i<filteredArray.count; i++){
    NSString *matchValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[filteredArray objectAtIndex:i]];
    if ([matchValue isEqualToString:dictionryKey]){
        [arrayForTableView addObject:matchValue];
    }
}
```

Use arrayForTableView array for your tableview

```
cell.textLabel.text = [arrayForTableView objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am getting crash that objectAtIndex 0 is beyond bounds which is logical since I did not typed any text in search bar yet so array is empty. So how can I show by allItems array before text is typed in search bar and only after text is typed tableView will start filling cells with sorted values?

Comment: Set number of row in section delegate method set " self.arrayForTableView.count" and make global array.And in textdidchange delegate set condition, if searchText is empty, return from there.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that you not updating `numberOfRowsInSection` delegate method for sortedArray

You need to check if search bar is active or not. if search bar is active then use sortedText array else if search bar is not active then use library.library array

For check search bar active create a global variable `isSearchBarActive` And assign it true value in `searchBarTextDidBeginEditing` delegate function and assign false in `searchBarTextDidEndEditing`

Add Condition in `numberOfRowInSection`

```
if searchBarActive {
    return self.sortedText.count
}
else {
    return library.library.count
}
```

Add Condition in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` like this

```
if searchBarActive {
    cell.textLabel.text = [self.sortedText objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] 
}
else {
    cell.textLabel.text = [library.library objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] 
}
```